# Is it an act of justice to abort an unborn child as that child would then go to heaven?

Tags: baptism, abortion, infants, justice

On the topic of unborn/infants dying without being baptized, could one argue that, as those babies would not go to hell but instead to heaven, it is an act of mercy or justice to abort babies to "guarantee" a spot in heaven?

Comment: How is this question different from "*When someone is baptized and has all their sins forgiven, wouldn't it be appropriate to kill them immediately before they can sin again?*"?

Comment: This question appears to be attempting to circumvent the rule about “asking if X or Y is a sin”.

Comment: Needs an "according to xxx" because the subject of unbaptized infants differs between denomination.  Hopefully we'd all agree this is an abhorrent idea though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure most Christian groups will point out the gross misunderstanding of "justice" here.  Justice is "giving someone their due", in this case giving the (still) helpless baby his/her due, owing to the *potential* flowering of this human individual to become an adult to handle the **gift of life** God has given him/her since conception.

Therefore, the right understanding of justice due to babies is that we adults owe them protection while they still cannot defend themselves, not to mention that we ALL were once babies and that we were able to reach this stage (adults sufficiently mature to participate in Christianity.SE) only through the help of our parents and our society.  It is the **natural sense of justice that we feel obligated to want to pass forward the gifts we have received from our parents/societies to those who need them**.  This is also the principle implicit in God's rebuking the powerful in Jerusalem for neglecting those who couldn't defend themselves: [the widows and the orphans](https://www.gotquestions.org/orphans-and-widows.html).

In Christianity, "heaven" is life in the world to come.  But this question is about life in THIS world.  Justice in regards to our eligibility to enter the world to come is for **God alone** to confer (in this case, justice given to aborted babies to gain admittance to heaven).  But justice in regards to a human being flourishing in THIS world, **God has delegated to us**, which becomes part of our society's obligation to administer to those who need it.  In the Bible there are multiple instances where those who denied justice in THIS world "cry out to God", implicitly asking God to take care of society's irresponsibility.

It's not Christian justice to posit that aborted babies *have* received their full "due" because most likely God will admit them to heaven.  An axiom of Christian justice (supported Biblically) is that when a human is conceived, **he/she immediately possesses human rights given by God alone**, **a gift purely from God** to which not even their parents contribute (i.e. their parents don't give them this right).  Part of this right is to flourish in THIS world as well.  It's **both-and**, not **either-or**.  Therefore, the answer is a very obvious **NO**.

Comment: So aborting children and guaranteeing them a spot in heaven is not justice? How come?

Comment: It's not justice because they have the right to live in THIS world as well.  It's **both-and**, not **either-or**.  It is an axiom of Christianity that when a human is born, they immediately possess human right given by God alone; part of this right is to flourish in this world.  Your notion of justice is not Christian.

Comment: Ah now I know how to reply to this argument, thanks!

Comment: @uggupuggu You're welcome.  Have a blessed day.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple. You might consider upvoting tge question since yiu deemed it worth answering and were rewarded by op

Comment: @uggupuggu, also, the argument is necessarily an "ends-justify-means" argument, which many would argue isn't a good argument in itself. Here's a fun point of comparison; is it okay to torture someone (inquisition-style) if it increases their chances of being saved?

Comment: It's not justice because no one is owed salvation and even if someone were owed salvation, it isn't owed by the would-be killer to the infant in question.

Answer (score 0):

No, killing babies in order to take advantage of their innocence and use their “get into heaven free card” (so to speak) would not be considered justice.  Killing the person who is killing babies to take advantage of a **perceived** loophole (to allow them to murder children) quite possibly **would** be justice.

If one believes in pre-determinism, then those children’s future dates are already decided so they do not need assistance by murder before they can live out their lives.

If we are speaking in terms of free-will then you would be deny the children their right to choose their own actions which will lead them down their path.

Murder as a form of helping a person’s soul would be a misinterpretation although it has been used quite often through histor.